# Computer software - Transfer of data from android application to desktop application

Tags: android, database, connection-sharing

In android application data is stored in sqlite and I have to fetch that data in my desktop application if any solution or method available please let me know.

Comment: u can have sqlite on your desktop too

Answer (score 0):

*There are many useful Software available which could help you to transfer Data from your Android Cell phone to the PC.*

The best I can suggest you is, **SyncDroid**

it's free to download, enables to transfer SMS, Contacts, Call Logs, Bookmarks, Audio, Videos, Camera Photos and SD Card Photos between Android to Destop devices.

The built-in Backup & Restore tool allows to backup all the mobile files to PC easy. Also, you can restore your iPhone or Android whenever you want.

Comment: This suggests a tool, but doesn't explain how to accomplish the result, or link to the product.  Please see the guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Comment: We have to transfer data stored by android app to the application using database

Comment: could you please specify the APP you are using on cell phone & the Destination Database?